# Can I convert a tuple to a parameter list 'inline'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameters, tuples

`traceback.format_exception()` takes three arguments.

`sys.exc_info()` returns a tuple of three elements that are the required arguments for `traceback.format_exception()`

Is there any way of avoiding the two line "conversion":

```
a,b,c = sys.exc_info()
error_info = traceback.format_exception(a,b,c)
```

Clearly

```
error_info = traceback.format_exception(sys.exc_info())
```

doesn't work, because `format_exception()` takes three arguments, not one tuple (facepalm!)

Is there some tidy way of doing this in one statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `*` operator to unpack arguments from a list or tuple:

```
error_info = traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())
```

Here's the example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> range(3, 6)             # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3394898/334999 check this. A detailed explanation on * and **

Comment: Dang, I was googling for "flatten" where clearly I should have googled for "unpack"!   Thanks heaps, accept tick coming in 10 minutes :)